# Map with fast and constant get() for Java 7

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java-8, java-7

While using the HashMap that java 7 provides, i ran into the problem that get() evolves from O(1) to O(n) as described [here](http://www.nagarro.com/de/de/blog/post/24/Performance-Improvement-for-HashMap-in-Java-8) and solved in java 8.

But because i have to stick to java 7 and can't upgrade the project, i am looking for a library or any way to have a Map with a fast and constant get().

Comment: http://java-performance.info/hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove-january-2015/

Comment: A larger initial capacity will prevent more collisions between differing hashCodes (space/time costs). Best (for java 8 too) would be to check the created hashCodes for improvements.

Comment: Are you sure you really have that many hash collisions? What is your key type?

Comment: why not override HashMap and create your own with own coded get method

Comment: @JonSkeet: It seems to me that is the case. Over the runtime of the project, get() takes more and more time. The keys are Long objects

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. How many `Long` values, and how many collisions do you have? (It should be easy to find collisions...)

Comment: @Alexton What I would do in your place is replace your hashmap with a treemap and test the performance. Since treemap are guaranteed to be O(log n) If there is an improvment in performance then you really have that many collisions and the solution would be to override the hash function. If it's slower or you can't feel the improvement then the bottleneck in your application won't be coming from your hashmap.

Comment: Probably your original problem is that you iterate the map incorrectly (like using `keySet()/get()` instead of `entrySet()`).

Comment: 'Long' objects should not exhibit this behaviour. It should be rare for a `Long` to produce a colliding `hashCode` with an unequal `Long` before exhaustiung memory. I suspect there is a pattern in your values. Perhaps a `TrieMap` would be an possibility.

Comment: Just use a `TreeMap`. This has `O(log(n))`  complexity but will never degrade to `O(n)`. Since the maximum number of keys as limited for `Long` values, you can easily check wither the scaling different between hashing and binary search can ever become an issue.

Comment: How are you building your HashMap? Unless you have an unsualy pattern of use for `Long` values your problems are likely to be else where such as running low on heap space. Even if HashMap has 100 collisions which would be really exceptional it should still take less than 0.1 ms.

Answer (score 7):

The essence of the change in Java 8:

From your link [Performance Improvement for HashMap in Java 8](http://www.nagarro.com/de/de/blog/post/24/Performance-Improvement-for-HashMap-in-Java-8)

> Buckets containing a large number of colliding keys will store their entries in a balanced tree instead of a linked list after certain threshold is reached.

You could achieve the equivalent by reducing the number of *colliding keys* by improving your `hashCode` implementation.

Without details of your `hashCode` calculation or the pattern of the values it is difficult to advise further.